# I am not able to install tensorflow text

Tags: python, tensorflow, gemma

I am trying to use tensorflow-text module for a gemma fine-tuned model

I tried using and keep getting this error

PS C:\Users\Pratham\Desktop\Pycharm\ChatBot\Gemma> pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.16.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.16.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.16.1

Tensorflow version 2.16.1
Python 3.11

Comment: Why specifically `2.16.1` does you have any version requirements?? If not install directly let the `pip` pick compatible version `pip install tensorflow-text`

Comment: Here is link https://www.tensorflow.org/text